# Magento 2 Problem With CSS Loading

Tags: magento2, css, theme-fallback

Whenever I edit `app/design/frontend/Dzinehub/Theme/web/css/styles-l.css` , it doesn't get reflected in the front end when I load the site .After every change , I have to clear the cache and run static content-deploy for the changes to appear.Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself , You need to enable the apache server rewrite. Just follow these steps if you are a linux user ,Goto terminal and type

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

You need to restart the web server now to apply the changes:

> sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

You could run: `setup:static-content:deploy` OR delete the file(s) manually `pub/static/frontend/...`

While developing the first approach could be extremely slow so personally I prefer to remove the created files.

You can find a detailed explanation about code clean [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html)

BTW: It is preferable edit *.less* instead *.css* files to maintain scalable and 'neat' your theme code.

Comment: Does this mean I've to clear and run static-content:deploy every time I make a change in the stylesheet?

Comment: No, one or anorher

Answer (score 1):

If you set Magento to be in developer mode,"Static view files are not cached; they are written to the Magento pub/static directory every time they’re called" as it describes here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

You can set developer mode with cli: `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.

Also make sure you've disabled the Magento cache through the admin, and review the link I proved above which talks about the other modes available in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**”.

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

**I hope this may work for you. :)**

Answer (score -1):

Clear static files in cache management then run deploy.